# Does FIPS have any PAKE algorithms?

Tags: fips-140, pake

Are there any password-authenticated key exchange (PAKE) algorithms in FIPS standards?

Comment: [This query](https://www.google.com/search?q=PAKE+site%3Anist.gov) does not find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any password-authenticated key exchange (PAKE) algorithms in FIPS standards?

Not formally, no.  On the other hand, you could cobble together, say, EKE from DH and FPE (both of which has FIPS approved instantiations), and I expect that combination would be FIPS approved...